# strange choice of constant when showing $an + b = O(n^2)$ ("Introduction to Algorithms" book)

Tags: algorithm-analysis, asymptotics

In the third edition of [Introduction to Algorithms](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-algorithms), the authors state:

> ... when $a$ > 0, any linear function $an+b$ is $O(n^2)$, which is
>   easily verified by taking $c = a + |b|$ and $n_0 = max(1, -b/a).$

[In the above, $c$ and $n_0$ come from the standard definition of big-oh:

$f(n)$ is in $O(g(n))$ if there exist positive constants $c$ and $n_0$ such that $0 \le f(n) \le cg(n)$ for all $n \ge n_0$.]

I have no trouble accepting that $an+b \in O(n^2)$, but I'm questioning the motivation/origin of the weird choice of $n_0$.

If we assume that $ n \ge 1$, then, since $a > 0$, we have $an^2 \ge an$ and since $n^2 \ge 1$ we have $|b|n^2 \ge |b| \ge b$, implying that $(a+|b|)n^2 \ge an+b$. So it seems that $n_0$ could simply have been taken as $1$. Or am I messing up somewhere?

Comment: Because of requirement $an+b > 0$. It requires $0 \leq f(n)$

Comment: @fade2black ah okay, I had missed the clause that $0 \le f(n)$. Thanks!

Comment: you can remove this question otherwise it will be reposted repeatedly.

Comment: Why do you feel  I should remove it? I think it might help someone else making the same mistake as me. (btw if you were to post your comment as an answer I'd be happy to accept it.)

Comment: I have noticed that questions without accept are posted repeatedly by the @Community user, even though they have excellent answers.

Comment: They're not reposted: they just get bumped up to the top of the list from time to time. It's hardly a problem and certainly not a reason to delete the question. But it _is_ a reason to post answers as answers, not comments, as you've now done. (Actually, I think it's questions without accepted answers that get bumped.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby It's **indeed** questions without accepted answers that get bumped up.

Comment: an+b is of course O(n^2) but it is even O(n). Did you read it correctly?

Comment: @miracle173, I know an+b is O(n) (and even $\Theta(n)$). That was not the point of the question.

Comment: @miracle173 I guess your question stems from lack of context (as I only quoted the text relevant to my question). Taken from the beginning, the sentence actually goes: "What may be more surprising is that when a > 0, any linear function an+b is O(n^2)", the potential "surprise" according to the authors being an+b is not only O(n) but also O(n^2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the requirement $an+b>0$. The definition requires $0 \leq f(n)$.